# Kodexplorer, кирилические названия файлов выводятся на китайском

Tags: php, файлы, кодировка

Скачал этот на самом деле очень неплохой файловый менеджер на php KodExplorer. 
Все работает отлично, но есть одна проблема.
Если я смотрю им свой диск C: (windows 7) то все файлы и папки названые по-русски подписаны китайскими иероглифами [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же я через KodExplorer создаю новую папку с рускким именем., то в Windows она называется вообще набором спец. символов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто-то сталкивался? Кодировка файлов самого KodExplorer - `UTF-8 без BOM`

Comment: Какая версия php у вас? (`php -v`)

Comment: @ЕгорБанин php5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [config.php на 81 строке](https://github.com/kalcaddle/KodExplorer/blob/master/config/config.php#L81) есть упоминание китайской кодировки `gbk` на windows системах для версии php < 7.1, надо выставить кириллическую кодировку `cp1251` (или какая сейчас там? возможно `utf-8`). Как я понял задать `systemCharset` через пользовательский конфиг нельзя, придётся отредактировать файл config.php.

Comment: В точечку Егор. поставил $config['systemCharset']='cp1251', сразу заговорил по-нашему. Большое Вам спасибо.