# Kodexplorer, кирилические названия файлов превращаются в нечитабельные названия при архивации и последующем скачивании

Tags: php, веб-программирование, кодировка

Файловый менеджер радует наличием функций и возможностей, но появилась проблема.
Директории на кириллице при упаковке и последующем скачивании становятся нечитабелиными.
 [По этой рекомендации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/897348/kodexplorer-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC/1018635#1018635) настройки выполнил, но не помогает.
[image: вид названия после архивации]
Как видно на скрине, на самом сервере директория и названия архива имеют нормальный вид, а вот если открыть архив, там уже кодировка другая.
Подскажите, что нужно еще поправить?

Comment: Режим передачи поставить "двоичный"

Comment: в файле pcltar.lib.php поправил кодировку с $v_stored_filename = zip_pre_name($v_stored_filename,'utf-8'); на $v_stored_filename = zip_pre_name($v_stored_filename,'cp1251');   после этого директории с кириллицей нормально упаковываются в *.tar и *.tar.gz, но остался вопрос с архивацией в *.zip, на сколько я предполагаю за эту архивацию отвечает файл pclzip.class.php но в нем изменения кодировки не нашел. Подскажите, где в файле pclzip.class.php задать нормальную кодировку для кириллицы для получения нормальных zip архивов?